# How to use the new Azure SDK for php on a ftp server

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I am now using the old Windows Azure SDK for PHP (2011).

```
require "../../Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Blob.php";

$accountName = 'resources';
$accountKey = 'accountkey';
$storageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob('blob.core.windows.net',$accountName,$accountKey);

$storageClient->blobExists('resources','blob.jpg');
```

I want to upgrade to the new SDK but don't know how to install it manually.

The website is running on an "Azure Webapp" via FTP.

I managed to find that I need to copy the "WindowsAzure" folder, and reference the classes I need, but how?

I followed the instructions on this page https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/php-download-sdk/ but got stuck after that.

edit: I have no experience with pear or composer, I want to manually install (upload) it via ftp.

---

EDIT:
Now I've got the following:

```
require_once('WindowsAzure/WindowsAzure.php');

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

// Create blob REST proxy.
$connectionString='DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=ttresources;AccountKey=***************';
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

$container = '87d57f73-a327-4344-91a4-27848d319a66';
$blob = '8C6CBCEB-F962-4939-AD9B-818C124AD3D9.mp4';

$blobexists = $blobRestProxy->blobExists($container,$blob);

echo $blobexists;
echo 'test';
```

The line `$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);` is blocking everything that happens after it.

---

After including the HTTP/Request2.php, the page told me to place the Net/Url2 and the PEAR package in the root of my project (the same dir as where I have the page that loads the windowsazure.php), they can be found at:

http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/redirected

http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the lasted Azure SDK for PHP on GitHub repository at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php. Then upload the `WindowsAzure` folder to your Azure Web Apps via FTP.

And include the SDK in PHP scripts like:

```
require_once 'WindowsAzure/WindowsAzure.php';
```

As in new Azure SDK for PHP, it requires some other dependencies. As your script is blocked at `$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);` you may check whether you have and dependency [`HTTP/Request2`](https://github.com/pear/HTTP_Request2). New SDK leverages it to handle http requests.

You may require this dependency first. Also, you can enable `display_errors` for troubleshooting.

And in new SDK, it seems there is no function `blobExists` any more. In stead, you may try :

```
// Get blob.
$blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob("mycontainer", "myblob");
if ($blob) {
   //blob exists
}
```

Comment: Ok and how do I go from there? Lets say I just want use the "blobExists" function. When I got that, I guess I can figure out the rest by myself.

Comment: It's working now but it takes about 14 seconds for the page to load :(. I also had to place the Net/URL2 and the PEAR package in my project root. Any idea how to reduce the page load time? :/

Comment: It is the function "getBlob" that takes so long, when I echo the performance before that, it takes 0 seconds, after it it takes 14 seconds.

Comment: Ok, not so smart of me, the "blob" it is getting is a video, so it's not so strange that it takes so long, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: One more question, where can I find a list of the functions that I can use with the SDK?

Comment: You can directly check in the SDK source code. E.G. You want to know how manage blob storage, you can refer to the [WindowsAzure/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php), all the functions without `_` can be used via this instance. Also there detailed comments for these functions